# Invalid fields when using "Use completer" in Layer properties

Tags: qgis

I'm using the latest release of QGIS 2.18.9.

I've made a field in a layer without NULL and connected by relation to a fixed list of values from another layer. Then I checked "Use completer" option (you can see it in the picture).

[image]

When I make a new object in that layer I always get invalid values just like I would still have null in that field. I can't put any objects in that layer.

[image]

When I uncheck "Use completer" in properties I have to use a list of choices in that Field and this way gives no error.

I want to use completer because its a better option when typing geographic names in a field.

Did someone encounter this kind of problem before?

Comment: Thank you for posting this question! I've the same issue with QGIS 2.18.14: "Not null" constraint works fine in a lot of cases, but on a Field "Value Relation" as soon as I add the option "Use completer" the field is always considered invalid even if a value has been selected. As soon as I add a value, the red coloration of the Field fade away giving the feeling it's ok but the "Invalid fields" message doesn't dissaper and the OK button stay greyed (and it's impossible to save). Did you or someone else find a solution for that problem?
Is there any known limitation about the use of "constraint

Comment: There is a ticket about that: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16676